# Ubuntu can't connect to WiFi network AR9227

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

I just installed Ubuntu 17.04 And I have problems with my WiFi card. It can detect networks but it can't connect. I've tried wicd but it just said Bad Password even if it was right one.

Output of lshw:

```
  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9227 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 6
   bus info: pci@0000:04:06.0
   logical name: wlp4s6
   version: 01
   serial: <censored>
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.10.0-20-generic firmware=N/A latency=168 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:20 memory:fe800000-fe80ffff
```

I have an TP-Link TL-WN751ND

wireless-info.txt: https://pastebin.com/puiDDuwN

Comment: Please remove the incorrect driver and try again: `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source` Reboot.

Comment: @chili555 Problem still occurs. It was happening earlier on previous versions.

Comment: May we see a new wireless-info paste?

Comment: @chili555 It was already posted in the first post wireless-info.txt: https://pastebin.com/puiDDuwN Here is the new one https://pastebin.com/U4qR3tr9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to that problem was in BIOS, I had to enable IOMMU and EHCI. Now all my problems with USB ports and WiFi are gone.